# XPath how to create a path to an attribute dynamically

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I am making a table where the header names are from the **header** element, and the data is obtained from the **attributes** of the **reportdata** elements.  However, I do not know the names of the attributes: *Value1, Value2, ect..* ahead of time. The names of the attributes are generated and stored into the **FieldName** attribute which is inside of the **column** elements inside of the **reportnode**.

I have not been able to find a way to make an XPath that uses the generated **FieldNames** and obtains the corresponding attribute's value from **reportdata**. Any ideas? Or is this not possible.

The following is the XML:

```
<report>
    <reportparameters>
        <header Order="1" HeaderName="Day_1" />
        <header Order="2" HeaderName="Day_2" />
        <header Order="3" HeaderName="Day_3" />
        <header Order="4" HeaderName="Total" />

        <reportnode ColumnCount="4">
            <column Order="1" FieldName="Value1" />
            <column Order="2" FieldName="Value2" />
            <column Order="3" FieldName="Value3" />
            <column Order="4" FieldName="TotalValue" />
        </reportnode>
    </reportparameters>

    <reportdata Value1="0" Value2="0" Value3="0" TotalValue="0"/>
    <reportdata Value1="0" Value2="0" Value3="0" TotalValue="0"/>
    <reportdata Value1="0" Value2="0" Value3="0" TotalValue="0"/>
    <reportdata Value1="0" Value2="0" Value3="0" TotalValue="0"/>
    <reportdata Value1="0" Value2="0" Value3="0" TotalValue="0"/>
</report>
```

The XSL attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <report>       
            <row>
                <xsl:for-each select="/report/reportparameters/header">
                    <xsl:variable name="columnCounter" select="position()"/>
                    <xsl:element name="{./@HeaderName}">
                    <xsl:for-each select="/report/reportdata">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@{../reportparameters/reportnode/column[@Order=$columnCounter+1]/@FieldName}"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </row>
        </report>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What is the result that you are attempting to get? Please use distinct cell values so that we can understand the logic of the transformation.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I will definitely make sure I post my desired result next time. Luckily you were still able to help me without it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you could do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/report">
    <xsl:variable name="cols" select="reportparameters/reportnode/column" />
    <report> 
        <xsl:for-each select="reportdata">
            <row>
                <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()"/>
                    <xsl:element name="{$cols[$i]/@FieldName}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </row>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </report>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report>
  <row>
    <Value1>0</Value1>
    <Value2>0</Value2>
    <Value3>0</Value3>
    <TotalValue>0</TotalValue>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Value1>0</Value1>
    <Value2>0</Value2>
    <Value3>0</Value3>
    <TotalValue>0</TotalValue>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Value1>0</Value1>
    <Value2>0</Value2>
    <Value3>0</Value3>
    <TotalValue>0</TotalValue>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Value1>0</Value1>
    <Value2>0</Value2>
    <Value3>0</Value3>
    <TotalValue>0</TotalValue>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Value1>0</Value1>
    <Value2>0</Value2>
    <Value3>0</Value3>
    <TotalValue>0</TotalValue>
  </row>
</report>
```

---

This is assuming every `reportdata` has the same attributes, in the same order, corresponding to the order of `column` elements in `reportnode`. Otherwise it gets slightly more complicated.

OTOH, if - as shown in your example - the attributes of `reportdata` have the required names, it can be even simpler:

```
<xsl:template match="/report">
    <report> 
        <xsl:for-each select="reportdata">
            <row>
                <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </row>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </report>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The first solution worked well, but your second solution made me contemplate why I hadn't formatted my xml that way.  I made some changes to the way I was building my XML so that it is more intuitive and now I can use your second solution.  Thanks so much!